# MySQL import database error because of extended inserts

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a 400MB (uncompressed) MySQL database. I'm using BIGDUMP, and I am getting this error:

> Stopped at the line 387.
>
> At this place the current query includes more than 300 dump lines. That can happen if your dump file was created by some tool which doesn't place a semicolon followed by a linebreak at the end of each query, or if your dump contains extended inserts. Please read the BigDump FAQs for more infos.

I believe the file does contain Extended Inserts, however I have no way to regenerate the database as it has been deleted from the old server. How can I import this database or convert it to be imported?

### Edit

It appears the only viable answer is to separate the extended inserts, but I still need to figure out how to split the file as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to import the database successfully after increasing the memory buffer and doing an ordinary MySQL import via SSH.

I used the following command with the absolute path:

```
mysql -u <username> -p < /home/dir/dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: How did you increase the memory buffer? I realise it's an old question, but I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @chmac It was a long time ago but I believe the setting was innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf or my.ini.

Answer (score 39):

You don't need to make any changes to .sql file:
just open bigdump.php in any text editor, find the line

```
define ('MAX_QUERY_LINES',300);
```

and replace 300 with anything you want.

Comment: This did it for me, thanks. Except for bigdump.php version 0.35b, the line is: $max_query_lines = 300;

Answer (score 9):

Just edit the dump file so that after 300 inserts you start a new statement:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`) VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'b'),
    (2, 'c', 'd'),
    (3, 'e', 'f'),
    -- snip --
    (300, 'w', 'x');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`) VALUES
    (301, 'y', 'z'),
    (302, ... etc
```

You can do this by just opening your `<backup>.sql` file in any text editor, it's just plain text. Sometimes a backup might be a `.gz` or `.bz` file, but they're just zips: if you decompress these gzipped or bzipped files, you'll end up with a single `.sql` file which you can edit easy.

It probably wouldn't be too hard to write a script to split each statement after an arbitrary number of lines. The basic program logic would look like this, perhaps:

1. find a line that starts with "INSERT".
2. copy the line up until the end of the word "VALUES"
3. step through all the following lines, counting up as you go.
4. if your counter reaches 300, then add a semicolon to the end of the last line and paste in the "INSERT ... VALUES" statement from before. Reset your counter to 1 and go to step 3.
5. if you reach a line that starts with "INSERT", reset the counter to 1 and go to step 2.

Though, you could just do this one manually, and then make sure that all future backups don't use extended inserts. Also, phpMyAdmin lets you set a maximal statement size when creating an export, so it'll do the above for you, basically.

Though, what you did with the memory limit is probably a much easier solution. For anyone else in a similar situation who can't change those limits, try the above.

Comment: How can I edit the file? I have no idea how to automate this process.

Answer (score 7):

For me it worked as follows:

Search for

```
$max_query_lines = 300;
```

then simply replaced to

```
$max_query_lines = 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `bigdump.php` and change the following line:

```
$max_query_lines = 300;
```

to this:

```
$max_query_lines = 300000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the 'max_query_lines' and 'INSERT' solutions!

"Both solutions have some drawbacks. Without extended insert, output dump will be many times larger than the dump with extended inserts. Increasing max_query_lines will increase the memory usage of bigdump script and your server might run out of the memory."

Source: http://www.etctips.com/error-at-this-place-the-current-query-includes-more-than-xxx-dump-lines/